# Delete table from hive not working

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to delete rows from table A whose column c is greater than max of column c of table B

I tried

```
delete * from A
where A.p >= (select max(t.c) from B t)
```

but it is not working . How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The INSERT ... VALUES, UPDATE, and DELETE statements require the following property values in the hive-site.xml configuration file:

```
hive.enforce.bucketing               true

hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode    nonstrict
```

After updating the configuration in the corresponding hive-site.xml, restart the services – HiveServer2 and Hive Metastore.

then, use this hql

```
delete from A
where A.p >= (select max(t.c) from B t)
```

Comment: Which version of hive are you talking about?

Comment: As of Hive version 0.14.0: INSERT...VALUES, UPDATE, and DELETE are now available with full ACID support.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues here:

1. [DELETE support](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Delete) itself is available starting from Hive 0.14 only.
2. The DELETE syntax should not contain asterisk ("*"). Refer the official [Hive Delete syntax](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Syntax.5).
3. Also as rightly pointed out by [MysticForce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5906757/mysticforce), Subqueries in where clause are only supported with IN, NOT IN, EXISTS, NOT EXISTS statements. Please refer [Subqueries syntax in manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries).

Comment: Will the subquery work in where clause in hive without having a correlation?

Comment: @MysticForce - The subquery used is NOT a "correlated subquery". By definition, Correlated Subquery is a subquery (a query nested inside another query) that uses values from the outer query. In this example, the subquery does not use any value from the outer query. All it does is to calculate the MAX value independently.

Comment: subqueries in where clause are only supported with IN , NOT IN , exists , not exists statements . please refer https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries